# splitting a list into two lists based on a unique value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
hello 12
hello 56
world 25
world 26
```

Is there a way in python that I can somehow parse the list that I obtain from reading this data to obtain two separate nested lists (or a numpy array)? One for the first two rows containing hello and the other for the next two rows containing world. I basically need to get a separate nested list for something unique in the first column (so "hello" and "world" are not previously known).

Comment: How exactly should the result look like for the sample data? Why are you talking about nested lists?

Comment: So you want to group by the first column?

Comment: `print(list(set(x.split()[0] for x in lst)))` It would be better if you would post an expected output

Comment: Use a dictionary to group using the  first column as the key appending the lines to a list

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit I actually have not tried anything yet. Just looking for pointers or a library, not necessarily an exact solution, didn't know if there was a way to split if I didn't know the unique words beforehand.

Comment: @timgeb It doesn't necessarily have to be a nested list. I just want to extract the numbers (in the second column) for each unique word in the first column.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks Padriac, I am going to try that.

Comment: @QPTR, I added an example that will group the second column values based on the value of the first, if the data is split into two sections then the groupby will be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *dict* and group by the first column:

```
from csv import  reader
from collections import defaultdict
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in reader(f,delimiter=" "):
        d[k].append(v)

print(d.values())
```

Which will give you all the values in two separate lists:

```
[['25', '26'], ['12', '56']
```

If the data is always in two sections you can use a groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
from csv import  reader
from operator import itemgetter

with open("in.txt") as f:
    print([list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) 
           for k, v in groupby(reader(f,delimiter=" "), key=itemgetter(0))])
```

Which will give the same output:

```
 [['12', '56'], ['25', '26']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just tried this, and it works pretty good. The second method you used is something I am going to parse a little bit to understand more.

Comment: No worries, the groupby just groups consecutive elements that have the same first element i.e itemgetter(0). We just pull each second element from from each group which is each v in the comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to be sure what data structure would be appropriate to store the result, let me suggest an ordered dictionary mapping the keywords in the first column to a list of the integer values (in order of their appearance):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> result = OrderedDict()
>>> with  open('input.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         key, val = line.split()
...         result.setdefault(key, []).append(int(val))
... 
>>> result
OrderedDict([('hello', [12, 56]), ('world', [25, 26]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I won't be able to accept your answer as well, but I did try it and works very nicely. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

loop this:

```
dict={}
#start the loop here
x=readdatafromfile.split()

if x[0] not in dict.keys():
    dict[x[0]] = list()
dict[x[0]].append(x[1])

#end loop here
print dict.keys() #for first column
print dict['hello'] #for list of values of hello
```