# How to split a list into sublists based on unique values of one column?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list and want to split it based on unique values of its last column in python. This is my list:

```
pnt=[[1.,2.,4.,'AA'], [0.,0.,0.,'AA'], [2.,1.,0.,'AA'],\
     [0.,-3.,1.,'BB'], [2.,5.,8.,'BB'], [.1,3.,0.,'CC']]
```

I want to get it as:

```
pnt=[[[1.,2.,4.,'AA'], [0.,0.,0.,'AA'], [2.,1.,0.,'AA']],\
     [[0.,-3.,1.,'BB'], [2.,5.,8.,'BB']], [[.1,3.,0.,'CC']]]
```

I read [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929137/splitting-a-list-into-two-lists-based-on-a-unique-value) but still cannot solve my issue.

Comment: `itertools.groupby` with a key

Comment: Dear @Jean-François Fabre, how can I use this method you mentioned? I have seen it but I have no idea ho to use it for doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` is the function you need. It needs to be customized to check key from the fourth element of each list.

Then elements and the return value itself needs to be forced to `list` to see the actual result (else it's optimized as generator functions). We discard the key (with `_`) because we're only interested in the elements, not the value that was used to group them.

```
import itertools

pnt=[[1.,2.,4.,'AA'], [0.,0.,0.,'AA'], [2.,1.,0.,'AA'],\
     [0.,-3.,1.,'BB'], [2.,5.,8.,'BB'], [.1,3.,0.,'CC']]

print([list(x) for _,x in itertools.groupby(pnt,lambda x:x[3])])
```

result:

```
[[[1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 'AA'], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'AA'], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 'AA']],
 [[0.0, -3.0, 1.0, 'BB'], [2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 'BB']],
 [[0.1, 3.0, 0.0, 'CC']]]
```

note that this method will group the *consecutive* groups only.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` to get the desired output.

**Ex:**

```
pnt=[[1.,2.,4.,'AA'], [0.,0.,0.,'AA'], [2.,1.,0.,'AA'],\
     [0.,-3.,1.,'BB'], [2.,5.,8.,'BB'], [.1,3.,0.,'CC']]

result = {}
for i in pnt:
    result.setdefault(i[-1], []).append(i)  # Form Dict with key as last value from list and value as the list

print(list(result.values()))    # Get Values of Dict
```

**Output:**

```
[[[1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 'AA'], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'AA'], [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 'AA']],
 [[0.0, -3.0, 1.0, 'BB'], [2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 'BB']],
 [[0.1, 3.0, 0.0, 'CC']]]
```